# how is convert and fix error in this code to CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how is convert this code to CodeIgniter code:

search_hotel: -> this is CI_Model

```
return mysql_query("select * from hotel_submits where name LIKE '".$searchterm."'")
```

i try but have error:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', '$searchterm')->get('hotel_submits');
        return $query->row();
```

error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given
Filename: admin/tour.php
Line Number: 15


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: admin/tour.php
Line Number: 21
```

code:-> this is CI_Controller

```
$searchterm = $this->input->post('search_hotel');
$result = $this->model_tour->search_hotel($searchterm);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { //this is line 15
//giving names to the fields
$data = array (
   'name' => $row->name,            
);
}
echo json_encode($data);  //this is line 21
```

Answer (score 3):

Think there's various things here.  In your model where you return $query->row() you are only going to return one recordset row.  You should try $query->result() instead.  I would also advise moving the code you have in your controller into the model as well. So you model would begin to look something like:

```
function search_hotel($searchterm)
{

$query = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', $searchterm)->get('hotel_submits');

$data = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   data[] = $row->name
}

return $data
}
```

So your controller simple becomes something like:

```
function your_controller() {
//Set your $search_term somehow

    echo json_encode($this->model('your_model_name')->search_hotel($search_term);
}
```

Hopefully that should start to point you on the right track.  Full information on creating and using recordsets can be found within the CI docs - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: The controller should `echo` the data, not `return` it.

Comment: `$this->model('your_model_name')` is invalid.  It should be `$this->your_model_name`.

Comment: for search result must use of foreach or while!?

Comment: @user837032: In this case, `foreach`.